# Cakephp: exposed virtual field are not included in query

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I read some other questions but they are very old. I'm using CakePHP 3.7.9.
I read the documentation about virtual fields, [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields) and [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-fields).

So far:

**Proforma.php**

```
class Proforma extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'customer_id' => true,
        'proforma_number' => true,
        'proforma_date' => true,
        'payment_date' => true,
        'proforma_state_id' => true,
        'customer' => true,
        'proforma_state' => true,
        'item_proformas' => true
    ];

    protected  $_virtual = [
        'total'
    ];

    protected function _getTotal()
    {
        $q = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('item_proformas')->find();
        $v = $q
            ->select(['total' => $q->func()->sum('total')])
            ->where(['proforma_id' => $this->id])
            ->first()['total'];
        if ($v == null) $v = 0;
        return $v;
    }
}
```

In views I can easily access to this field:

```
<td class="text-right"><?= $proforma->item_proformas ? $this->Number->currency($proforma->total) : '' ?></td>
```

But when I try to make a query in Controller, i.e.:

```
$query = $this->Proformas->find();
debug($query);
$query->select(['value' => $query->func()->sum('total')]);
```

The field `total` is not found. Here the output of the debug:

```
object(Cake\ORM\Query) {

    '(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
    'sql' => 'SELECT Proformas.id AS `Proformas__id`, Proformas.customer_id AS `Proformas__customer_id`, Proformas.proforma_number AS `Proformas__proforma_number`, Proformas.proforma_date AS `Proformas__proforma_date`, Proformas.payment_date AS `Proformas__payment_date`, Proformas.proforma_state_id AS `Proformas__proforma_state_id` FROM proformas Proformas',
    'params' => [],
    'defaultTypes' => [
        'Proformas__id' => 'integer',
        'Proformas.id' => 'integer',
        'id' => 'integer',
        'Proformas__customer_id' => 'integer',
        'Proformas.customer_id' => 'integer',
        'customer_id' => 'integer',
        'Proformas__proforma_number' => 'string',
        'Proformas.proforma_number' => 'string',
        'proforma_number' => 'string',
        'Proformas__proforma_date' => 'date',
        'Proformas.proforma_date' => 'date',
        'proforma_date' => 'date',
        'Proformas__payment_date' => 'date',
        'Proformas.payment_date' => 'date',
        'payment_date' => 'date',
        'Proformas__proforma_state_id' => 'integer',
        'Proformas.proforma_state_id' => 'integer',
        'proforma_state_id' => 'integer'
    ],
    'decorators' => (int) 0,
    'executed' => false,
    'hydrate' => true,
    'buffered' => true,
    'formatters' => (int) 0,
    'mapReducers' => (int) 0,
    'contain' => [],
    'matching' => [],
    'extraOptions' => [],
    'repository' => object(App\Model\Table\ProformasTable) {

        'registryAlias' => 'Proformas',
        'table' => 'proformas',
        'alias' => 'Proformas',
        'entityClass' => 'App\Model\Entity\Proforma',
        'associations' => [
            (int) 0 => 'customers',
            (int) 1 => 'proformastates',
            (int) 2 => 'invoices',
            (int) 3 => 'itemproformas'
        ],
        'behaviors' => [],
        'defaultConnection' => 'default',
        'connectionName' => 'default'

    }
}
```

**Why even if the virtual field is exposed it's not inserted into the query?**

The documentation linked above says:

> Do bear in mind that virtual fields cannot be used in finds. If you want them to be part of JSON or array representations of your entities, see Exposing Virtual Fields.

and then:

> By default virtual fields are not exported when converting entities to arrays or JSON. In order to expose virtual fields you need to make them visible. When defining your entity class you can provide a list of virtual field that should be exposed

So exposing virtual fields should let me to use them in finds.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of "Do bear in mind that virtual fields cannot be used in finds" isn't clear. See how you had to write a special function in PHP to do the calculation? What is your expectation regarding that being translated into SQL code such that it could be part of a query?

Comment: "Exposing" a virtual field is about making that field available when you convert your entities (which have already been read from SQL) into alternative representations.

Comment: Because English is not my primary language, I understood that exposing the virtual field leads them available to JSON and array (like queries). And the "if you want" just after "cannot be used in finds" sounded to me like the solution to use!

Comment: JSON and arrays are output formats, generated by running PHP code on query results. That code can add virtual fields by using your function. But it's all happening after the query has finished running.

Comment: So they are nothing like the "calculated field" for example in MS Access, aren't they? If I want to sum up all the rows I have to do manually every time I do a `find`. I hoped using a virtual field they are automatically calculated only when the rows change.

Comment: There's definite misunderstanding here. Virtual fields are to do calculations on a single entity. `_getTotal` would make sense on an order record, for example, where the columns include `price`, `tax` and `shipping`, and it adds those three up to give the total amount for that one order. If you want to total across multiple rows, that's a job for [query functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions) or perhaps a [custom finder](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Virtual fields are not calculated at the point the query is run. Here are some alternative approaches you may find helpful.

- Create View of the actual table ( handle the sum at the DB level)
- Create A beforeFind event in the table model.